# Is it possible to change browser arguments in the middle of the test in Playwright?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I am using **Python** + **Playwright** for testing.
And I use fake audio input in my tests with the "--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture" argument.

Is it possible?

1. to launch chromium with that argument
   `"--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=C:\\path\\first.wav"`
2. use first audio file as input
3. then I do some logic in my app
4. next I want second file to be played through the fake mic, but I don't want to close the browser, I want to continue the same test in the same page, because of the logic of my test.
5. So ideally I just want to pass new value for the argument in the middle of the test
   `"--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=C:\\path\\second.wav"`

Anyone has any similar experience? How to do that?

I tried overwriting first.wav file with another file locally, but it does not work. Seems like first.wav is already loaded in the browser and just played inside.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve by doing this in terms of functional requirement of your application?

Comment: You can't accomplish that without closing the browser.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal My scenario is like this: User tries to record the first audio sample; the quality is very low; the app rejects the sample and offers to try again; user records the second good/valid sample.